# How do I code this collision event (between the snake head(last item in the array) and the fruit) in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game of Snake using JS, html and CSS, having a problem with the JS. Specifically the collision event between the snake and fruit, where the snake eats the fruit and it disappears and reappears randomly. Is the if statement after the switch correct?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid div')
  const width = 10
  let currentIndex = 0
  let snakes = [2,1,0] //2 is head, 1 is body, 0 is tail
  let direction = 1


  snakes.forEach(snake => squares[snake].classList.add('snake'))

  setInterval(() => {
    const tail = snakes.pop() //removes the last item of the array
    squares[tail].classList.remove('snake')
    snakes.unshift(snakes[0] + direction)
    console.log(snakes)
    squares[snakes[0]].classList.add('snake')
  }, 1000)


  function moveMySnake(e) {
    squares[currentIndex].classList.remove('snake')

    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        direction = -1
        break
      case 38:
        direction = -width
        break
      case 39:
        direction = 1
        break
      case 40:
        direction = width
        break
    }
    if(snakes[0].contains('fruit')) {
      snakes[0].remove('fruit')
      fruitReappears()
    }

function fruitReappears() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)
    const randomSquare = squares[randomIndex]
    randomSquare.classList.add('fruit')

  }





  document.addEventListener('keyup', moveMySnake)
  document.addEventListener('keydown', e => e.preventDefault())
})
```

currently the snake just passes through the fruit and nothing happens?

Comment: didn't really read all the code but I think you wanted `if (snakes[0].classList.contains('fruit')) {snakes[0].classList.remove('fruit'); }` though I don't think you need the if at all. Just always remove `fruit`. You won't get an error if it does not exist.

Comment: Seems to be a syntax error in your code - it is missing a closing brace, I think for the function moveMySnake().  Are you including the correct/entire onReady function?